# Datetime string formatting and CultureInfo

Tags: c#, string, datetime, formatting

I was suprised to see FxCop complaining that I wasn't specifying a CultureInfo in the following:

```
string s = day.ToString("ddd");
```

Surely the format string param in `ToString` is completely independent of `CultureInfo`? Is there any way which `CultureInfo` could affect the returned string?

**EDIT:** sorry, this is a total fail of a question. It's obvious that `"ddd"` should be dependent on culture settings. I was really thinking more of a case like `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy")`, but it looks like FxCop doesn't in fact complain in that instance.

Comment: Note that `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy")` gives different outputs on CultureInfo ar-SA, th-TH, dv-MV, prs-AF and ps-AF. The format is the same but the dates will change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an article on MSDN on [How to extract the Day of the Week from a Specific Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911.aspx). You will find many different examples on culture on that page, including this one:

```
DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 6, 11);
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("ddd"));    // Displays Wed

DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 6, 11);
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("ddd", 
                  new CultureInfo("fr-FR")));    // Displays mer.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(day.ToString(), "ddd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo gives you default culture independent DateTimeFormatInfo.