# DateTime bound to a datagrid : Display in EU format, not US

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetime, data-binding

I have a datagrid in WPF.
In this datagrid, i display several bound DateTime.
The dateTime are displayed in US format, and i'm French, so, i would like to display it in EU format (dd/mm/yyyy).

Is there a way to directly set the DateTime format in EU whithout parsing it to a string ?
I would like to use the DateTime directly, not the string.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Don't know the solution by heart so can't help - sorry -, but why would you want to force this? The reason you're seeing it in US format is most likely because your PC settings are set to display this in US format. This is something you should leave and let the user decide how he wants it, in my opinion.

Comment: @JensenSomers Not necessarily. The US date format leaks in everywhere disregarding regional settings. One day the whole world will use ISO ( approx yyyy-mm-dd ) but until then we have to reformat and reformat and reformat.

Comment: Jensen not a very good answer Walter you can try the following creating a new instance of CultureInfo 
`CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr-ca");` 
`DateTimeFormatInfo dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();` forexample also Walter based on what I have stated earlier you can convert the date that you have to something like this for example `date.ToString(new CultureInfo("fr-ca"));`

Comment: If you need this for input then follow the answer. If you need that just for display then you can customize the format directly in the binding via the FormatString parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can change the `CultureInfo` or you can make a custom formatting string info here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

```
  // a global var
  string dtFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy";


  //where I'm displaying my DT
  Console.WrtieLine(myDT.ToString(dtFormat));
```

Info on `CultureInfo` which is what you'll want to use if you want to do any non numerical representations. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat(v=vs.71).aspx

There are also several easy to find SO questions with specific examples using `CultureInfo` such as this [Datetime string formatting and CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743417/datetime-string-formatting-and-cultureinfo) which shows how to display the three letter representation for a day in French.